# Terraform's random_shuffle don't shuffle as expected

Tags: terraform

I have this configuration :

```
variable "sub_list" {
  type    = "map"
  default = {
    "data.dev"  = ["data1", "data2", "data3", "data4"]
    "data.dev2" = ["data1", "data2", "data3", "data4"]
  }
}

resource "random_shuffle" "az" {
  input        = "${var.sub_list[local.data]}"
  result_count = "${length(var.VM_count)}"
}

data "vsphere_sub" "sub" {
  count = "${length(var.VM_count)}"
  name  = "${random_shuffle.az.result[count.index]}"
}

resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "VM" {
  name     = "${var.VM_name}
  folder   = "${var.folder}"
  count    = "${length(var.VM_count)}"
  sub_id   = "${element(data.vsphere_sub.sub.*.id, (count.index)%length(data.vsphere_sub.sub.id))}"
  num_cpus = "${var.VM_vcpu}"
  memory   = "${var.VM_memory}"
}
```

When I launch with `VM_count=2` for example, I expect to have a subnet for every VM but it creates the 2 VMs in the same subnet, and it shuffles just one time and not 2. How we could select randomly an item from a map based on the number of VMs to be created ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

A couple issues. You cannot get the length of a number so this

```hcl
count = length(var.VM_count)
```

should be

```hcl
count = var.VM_count
```

Unsure what this line's intention is but this

```hcl
sub_id = element(data.vsphere_sub.sub.*.id, (count.index)%length(data.vsphere_sub.sub.id))
```

should be this if we want a different subnet

```hcl
sub_id = element(data.vsphere_sub.sub.*.id, count.index)
```

so the final result would be

```hcl
resource "random_shuffle" "az" {
  input        = "${var.sub_list[local.data]}"
  result_count = "${var.VM_count}"
}

data "vsphere_sub" "sub" {
  count = "${var.VM_count}"
  name  = "${random_shuffle.az.result[count.index]}"
}

resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "VM" {
  name     = "${var.VM_name}"
  folder   = "${var.folder}"
  count    = "${var.VM_count}"
  sub_id   = "${element(data.vsphere_sub.sub.*.id, count.index)}"
  num_cpus = "${var.VM_vcpu}"
  memory   = "${var.VM_memory}"
}
```

Now when you apply with a `VM_count=2`, it should grab 2 random subnets from `sub_list` and create 2 VMs with each having a different subnet.